# How to use inline method when assigning to object

Tags: c#, linq

With LINQ to objects is there a way to assign a property using an inline method without defining the method separately?

For example, I have a list I am iterating over (results) to create a new list (testObjects) with the assigned values from the LINQ statement. The TestProp property has complex logic to populate it, so I want to perform that logic within an inline method in the LINQ statement, rather than calling a separate method.

Lets say for simplicity sake when assigning TestProp below, I have a property on results called DriverID which is a string value. In this assignment I need to make sure that the DriverID is a GUID before assigning it, and if so, assign it to TestProp. If not assign new Guid();

```
    var testObjects = results.Select(row => new
    {
     Name = row.Name,
     Address = row.Address,  
     TestProp = //I don't want to call a method like ConvertToGUID() here, I would rather do the work directly in the LINQ statement with something like 
              {
                //Do the work here instead by performing all the logic inline within this LINQ statement.              
              }
    }
```

I know you can call a method here directly to assign TestProp, but is there a way to keep all the method logic right in the 1 LINQ call property assignment instead so I do not have to define a separate method for the work that needs to occur to get the TestProp value?

Comment: Are you using LINQ to Objects (which only needs delegates) or EF etc, requiring expression trees?

Comment: I have edited the question to hopefully make it clearer what I am looking for.

Comment: Well did you look at the answer that I gave yesterday?

Comment: Yes, I was able to get a version of your answer to work, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using LINQ to Objects, your lambda expression only needs to be convertible to a delegate. So you can use something like:

```
var testObject = results.Select(row => {
    // Several statements here, as you wish
    int x = row.X;
    int y = row.Y;
    int z = x + y;
    return new {
        testProp = z,
        ...
    }
});
```

This won't help with LINQ providers using `Queryable` though, as statement-bodied lambdas are not convertible to expression trees.